# Using php lines in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Firstly, this is what my website looks like(now):[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cjDF.png)

And this is the code (saved in *.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
    <title></title>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">    
</head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function preset(){
        document.getElementById('lever1').style.backgroundImage = <?php include('lampa1_get.php');?>;   
        document.getElementById('lever2').style.backgroundImage = <?php include('lampa2_get.php');?>;
        document.getElementById('lever3').style.backgroundImage = <?php include('lampa3_get.php');?>;
    }
    function lever1() {
        <?php include 'lamp1_m.php'; ?>
        alert("a");
        window.location = "new.php";
    }
    function lever2() {
        <?php include 'lamp2_m.php'; ?>
        alert("b");
        window.location = "new.php";
    }
    function lever3() {
        <?php include 'lamp3_m.php'; ?>
        alert("c");
        window.location = "new.php";
    }
    </script>
<body onload = "preset();"> 
    <div id = "haz">
        <div id = "lever1" onclick="lever1();"></div>
        <div id = "lever2" onclick="lever2();"></div>
        <div id = "lever3" onclick="lever3();"></div>
        <div id = "lampa1"></div>
        <div id = "lampa2"></div>
        <div id = "lampa3"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>`
```

This is lamp1_m.php (lamp3_m- and lamp2_m are similar, only the table and the variables are changed in the SQL commad):

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
    $account = "root";
    $password = "";
    $name = "test1";
    $con = mysql_connect($host,$account,$password) or die("dead");
    mysql_select_db($name);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM lampa1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $wow = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $wow = $row['lampa1'];
    }
    if($wow == 1){
        $wow = 0;
    }else if($wow == 0){
        $wow = 1;
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO lampa1(lampa1) VALUE ('$wow')";
    mysql_query($sql);  
?>`
```

lampa1_get.php is aswell similar to lampa2_get and lampa3_get phps:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
    $account = "root";
    $password = "";
    $name = "test1";
    $con = mysql_connect($host,$account,$password) or die("dead");
    mysql_select_db($name);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM lampa1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $wow = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $wow = $row['lampa1'];
    }
    if($wow == 1){
        $wow = 0;
    }else if($wow == 0){
        $wow = 1;
    }


    $sql = "INSERT INTO lampa1(lampa1) VALUE ('$wow')";
    mysql_query($sql);


?>
```

By now, I hope you understand, that what this website does, is switch the levers. If a lever is switched, supposedly lever1 is switched, function lever1() should run, which would stand of connecting to the database, getting the last element in the lamp1 table, and if it's on(=1) turn it off(=0) and vice-versa.
Next thing is redirecting, so function preset loads the changes. My problem is... every time I switch a lever, all of them change, even tho' only the selected function runs.. Can you please help me fix this?

Comment: why are you reloading the page?? use ajax instead.

Comment: I reload because I set onload of body to run preset() function. That means it is only run when body is loaded, isn't it? And I need the 'backgroundImages' updated.

Comment: Totally impossible. PHP executes on the server, and your DB code will execute/exit long before the rest of page even reaches the user's browser. You need to use AJAX or something else for this.

Answer (score 2):

What ever you are trying to is not possible. Because `php` is server side language. Use ajax for this,

```
function lever1() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "lamp1_m.php",
        data: {},//use key:value if you want to pass any data
        success: function(data) {
             alert('a');
             window.location = "new.php";
        }

    }

});

function lever2() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "lamp2_m.php",
        data: {},//use key:value if you want to pass any data
        success: function(data) {
             alert('b');
             window.location = "new.php";
        }

    }

});

function lever3() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "lamp3_m.php",
        data: {},//use key:value if you want to pass any data
        success: function(data) {
             alert('c');
             window.location = "new.php";
        }

    }

});
```